# Unbound Syntax Error

Tags: centos7, internal-dns, unbound

I am trying to use unbound to forward requests to a pair of dns servers, while answering a small hand full of queries locally.  In testing this out, I have built the following configuration at `/etc/unbound/conf.d/my.zone.com.conf`

```
forward-zone:
    name: "my.zone.com"
    forward-addr: 1.2.3.4   # my DNS server
    forward-addr: 1.2.3.5   # my other DNS server

    local-data: "server1.my.zone.com. IN A 1.2.3.6"

    local-data-ptr: "1.2.3.6 server1.my.zone.com"
```

When running unbound-checkconf I get the following error:

```
$ unbound-checkconf
/etc/unbound.conf.d/my.zone.com.conf:8: error: syntax error
read /etc/unbound.conf.d/my.zone.com.conf failed: 1 errors in configuration file
$
```

My desired behavior is that unbound should forward all requests to the DNS servers `1.2.3.4`, and `1.2.3.5`, but should respond with local information for `server1.my.zone.com`.

I have looked through a number of lengthy config file examples on line, but I just don't see what I am doing wrong - though I suspect it has to do with `local-data` and `local-data-ptr` nested inside `forward-zone`.

The config file at `/etc/unbound/unbound.conf` remains unchanged from the default yum install in centos7.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, `local-data` and `local-data-ptr` are *server* options, not *forward-zone*. You should be able to simply add a server clause before them:

```
forward-zone:
    name: "my.zone.com"
    forward-addr: 1.2.3.4   # my DNS server
    forward-addr: 1.2.3.5   # my other DNS server

server:
    local-data: "server1.my.zone.com. IN A 1.2.3.6"
    local-data-ptr: "1.2.3.6 server1.my.zone.com"
```

Comment: And there I was putting `server:` at the top of the whole thing...   thanks, this worked.

Comment: The man page doesn't make it clear that clauses don't necessarily need to be grouped. Was a surprise for me too